# Does ProfileService.GetProfileDataAsync replace default scopes/claims in Identity Server 4

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

In a Identity Server 4 setup, I've added the scopes "email" and "profile" to a client. This causes the claims within these scopes to be added to the users token, which is sent from Identity Server to my application. This works as intended.

I needed to add a custom claim to the token. I did that using

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
            
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

    var claims = new List<Claim>();
           
    claims.Add(new Claim("Tenant", user.Tenant));

    context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
}
```

This also works, but I'm unsure whether it works as intended or not. When using this method all the claims added by default no longer gets added. I have to manually add claims from the scopes "email" and "profile". I do this in a manner like the following:

```
if (context.RequestedResources.ParsedScopes.Any(x => x.ParsedName == "email"))
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));
}

if (context.RequestedResources.ParsedScopes.Any(x => x.ParsedName == "profile"))
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
    claims.Add(new Claim("preferred_username", user.UserName));
}
```

Should this be necessary? is this working as intended or did I mess something up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from the explanation what implementation of `IProfileService` you use as a base.

If it is the [Default](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/4dc10e665f5ede63274427036c25cdc216130eb9/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/DefaultProfileService.cs) one, you can extend it like:

```cs
public override async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

    context.AddRequestedClaims(new[]{new Claim("Tenant", user.Tenant)});

    await base.GetProfileDataAsync(context); //here the default implementation adds 
                                             //claims from Subject (e.g. the cookie)
                                             //and logs the result
}
```

If you use ASP.NET Identity, you might want to play with [this one](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/4dc10e665f5ede63274427036c25cdc216130eb9/src/AspNetIdentity/src/ProfileService.cs).